# Do-Until Loop Stalling

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I am trying to use a 'Do Until' loop to take a value from list (Drop-down fields worksheet, starting at cell B19) and update a cell value another Excel Sheet (specifically, Data Collection worksheet, cell C1).  Once I can get this to work, I will add already functioning code to save the file based on the value in C1 in the Data Collection worksheet.

I am testing the code but it is constantly getting stuck after the pulling that first value.  Basically, it doesn't actually loop through the list until it ends.

I believe it has to do with what is classified as the active cell.  I think when I paste the value that changes the active cell.  I tried to correct this by re-iterating the active cell again.  This might be creating an infinite loop though.

Is there something I can do to adjust this?  Thank you in advance for looking at this and any replies you might have!  I based structure on the documentation found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/loop-through-data-using-macro

Code below:

```
   Sub Test2()
    ' Select cell to start loop, *first line of data*.
      Worksheets("Drop-down fields").Activate
      Range("B19").Select
      Worksheets("Drop-down fields").Range("B19").Copy
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
      Worksheets("Data Collection").Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      Worksheets("Drop-down fields").Activate
      Range("B19").Select
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
   End Sub
```

Comment: Without looking too much into the question, I recommend using `Sheets("sheetname").Cells(x,y)`  instead of `.activate` to read and set values

Comment: Also, if you're just getting into excel I highly recommend using [arrays to access large ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx#:~:text=To%20write%20a%20one%20dimensional,then%20write%20to%20the%20range.&text=This%20code%20will%20write%20the,wide%2C%20starting%20at%20range%20K1.) for performance reasons

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/62576)

Comment: Your `Do ... Loop` never advances, because in each iteration the code re-selects Range("B19"), then steps down one row. As written, it will never advance any further.

Comment: The biggest thing that you can do is avoid using `ActiveCell`. Just create you own references and work with those, i.e. `Dim x as Range : Set x = Worksheets("Drop-down fields").Range("B19") : x.Copy`. You should never be concerned with the active sheet or cell if you do it that way. Your code is then far more robust.

Comment: You would then do things like `Set x = x.Offset(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samuel,

Here's your code refactored to remove all the activates and selects and incrementing through you list in col B and copying to col C.

```
  Sub Test2()
   
      Dim wksSrc  as Worksheet
      Dim wksDst  as Worksheet
      Dim lSrcRow as Long
      Dim lDstRow as Long
      
      Set wksSrc = Worksheets("Drop-down fields")
      Set wksDst = Worksheets("Data Collection")
      lSrcRow = 19
      lDstRow = 1
      
      Do 
        wksSrc.cells(lSrcRow,2).Copy
        wksDst.Cells(lDstRow,3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        lSrcRow = lSrcRow + 1
        lDstRow = lDstRow + 1
      Loop Until wksSrc.cells(lSrcRow,lSrcCol) = ""
      
   End Sub 'Test2
```

Note: code is untested but I think I got all the references right.
HTH